# Does the tag bicycle=yes mean that its a preffered path for bicycles?

Tags: openstreetmap

If a path is tagged with

```
bicycle=yes
```

Does it mean that its a path where bicycles are allowed or is it actually a path that is preferred for bicycles (due to some reason like bicycle infrastructure)?

Edit:
I understand that the tag implies access but wanted to know if the tag can be used as an indication of a road more preferable for biking compared to roads thats don't have this tag.

Edit: To clarify my question further

I was mapping bicycle ways for a city and was wondering, since not every path has a bicycle tag, the ones that do have `bicycle=yes`, would they be more suitable for biking compared to the ones that don't have any' bicycle=*` tag (except the ones that imply cycling isn't allowed).

Comment: Low effort post. https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Bicycle

Comment: I did go through the wiki and understand that its indicates access, but was still confused if the tag can be used as an indication of a road more preferable for biking compared to roads thats don't have this tag.

Comment: @Jon please consider writing up your comment as an answer so we can consider this question resolved.

Comment: @lsj I guess I don't understand your question. According to the documentation, bicycle=yes only indicates ways where bicycles are permitted and has no (official) indication of preference. There are other tags for identifying dedicated bike paths, etc.

Comment: I was mapping bicycle ways for a city and was wondering, since not every path has a bicycle tag, the ones that do have 'bicycle=yes' (obviously the ones with other values like no are not suitable), would they be more suitable for biking compared to the ones that don't have any' bicycle=*' tag. (Also to clarify, I am aware that 'designated' and 'official' imply bicycle paths)

Comment: I did map all the other tags tat imply bike paths, just thought if I could show these as preferred for biking but I guess your comment does answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it mean that its a path where bicycles are allowed

Yes, just that.

> or is it actually a path that is preferred for bicycles (due to some 
>   reason like bicycle infrastructure)?

No.

First things first, access tagging *is* complicated.  In OSM as well as "yes" you'll also see values such as "designated", "destination", "customers" and others.  For "bicycle" you'll also see "dismount".  You can use [taginfo](https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/keys/bicycle#values) to see a list of values to expect.

As you suggest, bicycle infrastructure is useful to know about.  Depending on where you're looking in the world you might find:

- A highway tag such as highway=cycleway
- A surface tag
- Another tag like smoothness or surface
- The way you're processing might be part of a short or long distance cycle route.

All of these might help you infer whether the way you're dealing with is appropriate for bikes, and if so, what sort (i.e. a "racing" bike vs something for use offroad).